# How do I pass Pull Request ID to Command Line build task in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am attempting to create a build definition in TFS 2015 that is triggered after a Pull Request is created. It is triggered as part of a Branch Policy (Automatically Build Pull Requests).

I have a Command Line build task that uses the following:

```
Tool: C:\Path\To\My.exe
Arguments: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

My .exe creates folders and files depending on the PR ID from TFS. One of the folders is a direct copy of the PR ID (so the folder would be named "25" for PR 25).

Here is what my folder name looks like after my build runs successfully:

```
$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

As you can see, it is not evaluating the ID at build time.

How do I pass the PR ID to a command line executable build task using TFS 2015?

Comment: Check if the environment variable `SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID` is set. If it isn't, it's entirely possible that the documentation is incorrect and that TFS 2015 didn't expose that variable.

Comment: @DanielMann It seems it is not supported. I changed my .exe to use that Environment Variable and it was not provided at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` variable is not supported in TFS 2015.

I upgraded our TFS installation to Azure DevOps Server 2019 and it fixed the issue.

I found a [List of TFS Environment Variables](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2015/09/17/tfs-2015-build-environment-variables/) on the web that helped me with my answer.